# "Static" variable holding holding element loses value

Tags: javascript, element

So I'm Trying to make a "soft auto scrolling" function for and elements scroll-bar, basically its meant to be called then scroll an element for you. However as you can see in the code below I've encapsulated the function in a self-invoking function which holds the element in "element". However when it first reads the variable from the returned function in the line `else if (pos>element.scrollHeight)` element is returned as `null`

```
'use strict';
window.onload=(function() 
{
    window.scrollTo=(function()
    {
        var element=document.getElementById('more_info'),
            ease=function(pos)
            {
                var diff=(pos-element.scrollTop).
                    increment=(diff / Math.abs(diff));

                if (Math.abs(diff)<1)
                {
                    element.scrollTop=pos;
                    return;
                }

                else if (Math.abs(diff)<30)
                {
                    element.scrollTop+=1-(increment / diff);
                }

                else 
                {
                    element.scrollTop+=increment*10;
                }

                window.setTimeout(ease,1000 / 10);
            };
        return function(pos)
        {
            if (pos<0) {pos=0;}
            else if (pos>element.scrollHeight) {pos=element.scrollHeight;}
            ease(pos);
        };
    }());
}());
```

I Updated the code so that its called after the document loads, however my debugger seems to show that var element is still called before window.onload is

Comment: Could you post a fiddle to reproduce the issue?

Comment: are you aware the element already exists when your code is executing? it should work when you encapsulate all this into a ready/onload event

Comment: What do you mean by “element is returned as `null`”? Value of `element` variable is null in that place? The function you assign to `window.scrollTo` returns no value. Also you probably forgot to pass `pos` to `ease` in the call at the end.

Comment: Yeah oops, I was calling the script in the `<head>`

Comment: or always requery the element in `return function () { element = document.getElementById('more_info'); /*...*/ };` leaving `var element,` in the outer scope

Comment: I could do that, but now I'm more just curious as to why it's not working

Comment: @Palec Yes, at the point in time where `else if (pos>element.scrollHeight)` is executed element "is read" to be null, the function isn't meant to return anything. Thanks for catching the "ease" parameter

Comment: Do you really need those self calling functions? Makes it hard to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're executing the onload function immediately.

```
window.onload = (function () {
  ...
}());
```

That makes the function execute *then* assign the returned value as the `onload` handler.  This means it's executing before the DOM's ready.  Change it to remove the self-execution.

```
window.onload = function () {
  ...
};
```

Comment: oh jeez... I've been at it too long, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Time for a coffee break!